# How does this pipeline with printf -- "$(cat | sed...)" work?

Tags: shell, printf

What is going on in the first snippet with `printf --`? How does `printf` parse such a command and how does the final call stack look like?

```
$ printf '%x' 65537 | \
    printf -- \
    "$(cat | sed -E -e 's/^(.(.{2})*)$/0\1/' -e 's/(.{2})/\\x\1/g')" \
    | openssl base64 -e
AQAB
```

```
$ printf '%x' 65537 | \
    cat | sed -E -e 's/^(.(.{2})*)$/0\1/' -e 's/(.{2})/\\x\1/g' \
    | openssl base64 -e
XHgwMVx4MDBceDAxCg==
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be misreading the scripts you're asking about.

In the first example, the `printf` command is simply:

```
printf '%x' 65537
```

That will print the number `65537` as a hexadecimal value (`10001`).  The script then uses the shell pipe symbol (`|`) to pass the output of that `printf` command into the a second `printf` command:

```
printf -- "$(cat | sed -E -e 's/^(.(.{2})*)$/0\1/' -e 's/(.{2})/\\x\1/g')"
```

In this command, the `--` simply means "there are no cli options after this", which is used to ensure that anything after `--` that looks like an option is not treated like an option.  The remainder of the command is a shell `$(...)` expression, which will be replaced by the output of the commands contained inside the parentheses:

```
cat | sed -E -e 's/^(.(.{2})*)$/0\1/' -e 's/(.{2})/\\x\1/g')
```

It starts with a [useless use of cat](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html), which simply passes standard input  (...which is the output from the previous `printf` command...) to stdoutput.  The following `sed` command contains two expressions.  The first one...

```
s/^(.(.{2})*)$/0\1/
```

...matches any line containing an odd number of digits and prepends a `0`, ensuring that the every line has an even number of digits. The second expression...

```
s/(.{2})/\\x\1/g
```

Replaces every two characters (`nn`) with `\xnn`, which is a `printf` formatting code that asks `printf` to print the character with the given ASCII value.

The output from the second `printf` command is then piped into `openssl base64 -e`, which produces on `stdout` the base64 encoding of whatever was received on `stdin`.

---

So when you run:

```
printf '%x' 65537 | \
    printf -- \
    "$(cat | sed -E -e 's/^(.(.{2})*)$/0\1/' -e 's/(.{2})/\\x\1/g')" \
    | openssl base64 -e
```

This becomes:

```
echo 10001 | printf -- '\x01\x00\x01' | openssl base64 -e
```

Which outputs:

```
AQAB
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear and wonderful explanation. It's really helpful, now I realize the how 'printf --' works and what makes me confuse.